# How to teardown transaction with serializable isolation level after a transaction collision?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, isolation-level

What's the right way to handle collision with another transaction when serializable isolation level is used with PostgreSQL?

Assuming that the application has already executed

1. `begin transaction`
2. `...`
3. `savepoint p1`
4. `insert ...`

If the application gets error during step 4

```
ERROR 40001 could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict in checking.
The transaction might succeed if retried.
```

what is the correct teardown before retrying the transaction? Should application execute both queries

1. `rollback to savepoint p1`
2. `rollback`

or just `rollback`? If just `rollback`, can the name `p1` used for savepoint during the retry? Also, what if the step 4 above was successful but then executed

5. `release savepoint p1` ?

and that query was interrupted by `ERROR 40001`, should the application try to execute `rollback to savepoint p1` or would that result in error? Or would `release savepoint p1` succeed every time so there's no need to think what would happen if there's collision while executing it?

If there's some documentation about which queries cannot possibly result in transaction collision when executed at serializable isolation level, that would be great to find about.

Comment: Just `ROLLBACK;` will suffice, it'll rollback the entire transaction, with all its savepoints. You can use the names again in the new transaction, which is completely independent.